# What is the required value of correlation factor for a linear fit to have 99.9% accuracy

Tags: correlation, accuracy, curve-fitting

I am working on ADC characterization.ADC(Analog to Digital Converter) is a device used to convert any Analog signal into a digital equivalent (binary). I am feeding various values of DC (not changing with time)signals into it and recording the output. After plotting in excel. I have drawn trendline with linear curve fitting. It shows a correlation factor of 0.997. Is this correlation sufficient to have an accuracy(difference between actual value to measured value) of 99.9% i.e. error of <0.1%.

Comment: Please consider clarifying the concept more clearly for a broader audience (maybe explain ADC, as I do not believe this to be a statistics term), and more precisely describe what you mean by "accuracy" (e.g., if you are predicting something, clarify).

Comment: ADC = Analog to Digital Converter, this is why a DC signal is fed into the converter. Accuracy in this context is is relating to conversion accuracy, i.e. if given 5.0 volts for a converter range of 0.0 to 10.0 volts, the converter should yield 1/2 of the maximum digital output value. As a binary digital representation of the voltage can be displayed in the form of a decimal number, the question relates to the accuracy of that displayed conversion.

Comment: What is "error" in this case?

Comment: The difference between the reference input test voltage and the digitised output value. The converter integrated circuit chips also have many other specifications such as linearity, temperature sensitivity, drift, etc. but here the concern is with expected conversion accuracy. As a former engineer, I personally find the question to be clearly stated.

Comment: Your ADC is just a transformation, is it not?  If so the only reason it's not 1 is due to rounding error.

Comment: I have edited the question as per suggestions.There are 2 types of error in an ADC. first is the quantization error, second is the non-linearity error. Quantization error magnitude is known. Non-linearity will affect the accuracy as it's unknown. This is applicable for any system that is theoretically linear but practically has some non-linearity. My question is therefore applicable for all such systems. i.e. what is the correlation coefficient value for a linear system to have prediction error of <0.1%.